# pip not working (bad interpreter: /opt/homebrew/bin/python: no such file or directory)

Tags: python, pip

I am using python3 version: 3.10.6

When I enter "pip install mediapipe" in the terminal, it gives me the following error:

```
zsh: /opt/homebrew/bin/pip: bad interpreter: /opt/homebrew/bin/python: no such file or directory
```

echo $PATH shows:

```
/opt/homebrew/opt/python/libexec/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/share/dotnet:~/.dotnet/tools:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands:/Users/name/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools:/Users/name/Developer/flutter/bin
```

same error with `pip --version`

When I check `pip3 --version`, it shows the version and also show the same message.

```
zsh: /opt/homebrew/bin/pip3: bad interpreter: /opt/homebrew/bin/python: no such file or directory
pip 22.2.1 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip (python 3.10)
```

Comment: Have you delete /opt/homebrew/bin/python directory manually. Anyway, I think that you should try to reinstall pip rather than fix it manually

Comment: I have not deleted any path. it was working fine but now showing this error.

Answer (score 5):

I had solved it by updating path of bad interpreter in **/opt/homebrew/bin/pip** file.

In above file you can see that bad interpreter path, which you can update it with your installed version or correct path of interpreter.

For example, error in my case was while running `pip` command with any option as following:

```
zsh: /opt/homebrew/bin/pip: bad interpreter: /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.11/bin/python3.11: no such file or directory
```

So I replaced bad interpreter path in `/opt/homebrew/bin/pip` file by my correct interpreter path like:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I got the solution by just removing the `alias python=/usr/bin/python3` from `.zshrc`. now it's working but now the python and python3 version shows 3.9.12 instead of 3.10.6

Comment: Thank you, I had a similar issue with a different package.  I was operating in my anaconda base environment, used "which python" which led me to /Users/{myuser}/opt/anaconda3/bin/python.   I opened .zshrc and added the alias python="/Users/{myuser}/opt/anaconda3/bin/python" and restarted the terminal.  All fixed, thanks again for the head start